# Ubuntu installation usb strange behavior on laptop

Tags: system-installation, usb, ssd

I seem to be having difficulties trying to install Ubuntu on this computer. For reference, it's a "new" (never used) Crucial M500 220GB onto an Asus Q501la.

Here is what it gives me when I try to install: (I hope imgur links are ok)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wquZF.jpg

Compared to this, it just skips part 4 entirely:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

I've installed it successfully from the same USB flash drive onto the same SSD (different computer), but naturally it didn't pick up in the laptop due to different drivers and whatnot. I've wiped the drive, formatted it, even updated the firmware... no change.

The mobo picks up the SSD according to BIOS, which means it's connected just fine. However, when I boot the liveCD and type in "fdisk -l" only the usb shows up again. It feels like something really simple I'm missing, but I've spent a solid weekend trying to debug it to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using dual-boot?   Dynamic disks?  If not, is the hard drive connected to the first ATA port?